# C# Use REGEX to sort out Parentheses inside eachother

Tags: c#

im using REGEX right now to sort out lines like:

`string a  = "mine(hello, this())"
 string b  = "mine(hello, me.he)
 string c  = "mine(hello, this(this2())`

Im trying to get `this()` by itself.
Regex keeps messing up on this as the regex statement was made to get text inside of () how can I correct my regex statement to fix this.

Code:

```
string result = Regex.Match(a, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Is the single example in your question the only text the pattern will need to match?  I suggest adding more examples.  Will there ever be more than one level of nested parenthesis?  Will the second set of parenthesis ever have text in between?  I also suggest adding the regex tag to your question.

Comment: @CPerkins well, this is a mini environment im working on. Not the only pattern, ill update it now. Some will be mine mine(hello, "this") and also mine(hello, this.test) with that other one. I just need to get that single outside one. >(<my, insides()>)< the ones the >< are pointing at are the ones I need.

Comment: Okay, I see the edit and your comment provides more detail, but there are still some confusing details between the comment and the question.  I suggest merging your comment with the original question to provide a clearer goal.  Do you want `this()` as your question states, or rather you want everything inside the outermost parenthesis regardless of what else is inside, include mismatched parenthesis (like the string c example has)?  I'm being picky because a regex pattern is "picky".  It will match exactly what it is crafted to do.

Comment: ,(?<Pat>.+\(.*\))$  --- This Regex assumes that this() or similar will always occur after a Comma. Also, this regex will take all Ending brackets and will not be Bracket literate. Correct w ay to do this would be to parse the strings like the Balanced Paranthesis problem.

Comment: @CPerkins I want the the inside of the outermost parentheses. Sorry that I wasn't being specific enough...

Comment: @LoganRisen  Yes, your comment was quite specific.  Like I said, sorry if I seemed picky, but SO questions are best when they are edited to include relevant details rather than leaving such things in the comments.

Comment: Alright, so @CPerkins are you able to help me with the pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get everything inside the outermost set of parenthesis, use a greedy operator to get everything until the last parenthesis. The following pattern does not attempt to match sets of parenthesis or nested parenthesis.  (To do that is more involved and there are already many questions and online discussions about that.)

```
 Regex.Match(a, @"\((.*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

That pattern will match the opening parenthesis, then everything it possibly can until the closing parenthesis.  This will require backtracking, but should be reasonable if matches are limited to single lines.  Depending on current regex options, it could match across multiple lines and it has no other constraints, so it could match much more than desired.  If that is a concern, add additional operators to limit the extent that it matches.  For example, to keep from matching across lines:

```
 Regex.Match(a, @"\(([^\r\n]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```